# Best practices for managing eShop eCommerce?

Tags: team-management, methodology

It may be general question, but I would like to ask. 
What is your best advice/practices in managing eShop.

What methodology is best for managaing operations (orders, payments, logistic etc.)?
And what methodologies is best for projects parts like (marketing campain, developing new feature in shop). How to connect everything together, to avoid further problems.

This is my current team:

- team is 5-10 person
- each team member has different competence (1 graphic, 1 programmer, 1 copywrither, 1
  logistic etc.)
- team is distributed and works independently (team
  works from several location, and on different shifts)
- team meets once a week in main office

Comment: Firstly, if there is no end-date then it cannot be a project! A project but have defined outcomes/deliverables. Secondly it is virtually impossible for anyone here to answer your question because, broadly speaking, any model can be used to deliver any outcomes and which you choose depends on your local needs and certainly the preferences of the organisation. This question is therefore too broad and will likely be closed unless you are able to edit it to ask specific questions to meet specific PM issues.

Comment: I've corrected my answer. I want to know what is best way to manage a eShop? How to organize it to avoid mess in the future.

Answer (score 2):

### Separate the discretionary spending from operations

Any business has, broadly speaking, two kinds of spending:

1. Operations: This will cover resources and activities that are required to "keep the lights on". In your case this might include managing orders, logistics, maintenance etc. If you cut any of this, the business will come to a stand still. So, this is not discretionary.
2. Projects: You might have one or more discretionary projects. You will go through a cost-benefit analysis to determine which ideas you want to invest in and how much. Once one is approved, it becomes a project. Such a project will have a definite end date based on how much you decided it would be prudent to invest.

You use different methodologies for Operations and Projects. Without knowing the specifics of what you are trying to do, it is hard to answer. However, here is one example. Some people use Scrum for developing new features while they may use Kanban for the ongoing repetitive work. This may not apply in your case. As @Marv Mills said, please ask separate questions for each, providing more details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a "Best methodology". You should choose the one that you feel comfortable with, understand and respect the basic principles and suits your needs.

I suggest you do some research on all of them and based on that you make a decision